# Write access for non root users on file store using Kubernetes in GCP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-filestore

How to setup Kubernetes so that non root user can write inside the file store in GCP.

I tried below configuration in yaml file but still non root user is not able to write.

```
securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 1000
    fsGroup: 1000
```

Comment: Which version of GKE and are you using the built-in Filestore CSI driver?

Comment: @GariSingh I used 1.23.12-gke.1600 GKE and used built-in FIlestore CSI driver.